# resubmitting form not working after reload

Tags: javascript, forms, xmlhttprequest

In this simple app the unauthenticated user searches for restaurants with the city name,
and when the user chooses a restaurant, he can click on going but he needs to login with twitter first,

now when the user is back after authentication I want to resubmit the term the user inserted so he won't have to search again.
this is what I tried

```
form.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
 e.preventDefault();
 const xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
 xhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){

 if(this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {

   //format the data for the user interface
   const businesses = JSON.parse(xhttp.responseText);
   formatData(businesses);

   }

 }
 xhttp.open("post", "http://localhost:3000/api/", true);
 xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
 xhttp.send(`location=${input.value}`);

 //save searched term in a session
 sessionStorage.setItem('autosave', input.value);
 sessionStorage.setItem('refreshed', false);
});

//
//if the term is saved and the page is refreshed
//(will happen only when page is refreshed)
if (sessionStorage.getItem("autosave") && sessionStorage.getItem("false") == 'false') {
 //restore the contents of the text field
 input.value = sessionStorage.getItem("autosave");
 //then submit
 document.forms["myForm"].submit();
}else{
 console.log('no item')
};
```

This works but the problem is when the form is submitted automatically it redirects again to "http://localhost:3000/?location=new+york"
which results in data not displaying.

I don't know how to stop it from doing that.

Comment: This is not really an answer to your problem, but instead a architectural idea: If you user **can't** access the restaurant page _without_ been logged in, then maybe he shouldn't be able to search for them before logging in.

Comment: the user can search even when not authenticated, the problem is how do i keep the results after he authenticates. this is a problem caused by `document.forms["myForm"].submit();` since it reloads the page, and i want to stop it from doing that.

Comment: I see, then you can do the same you did with the other form, preventing it's default operation.

Comment: the line i provided submit's the same form not another one. and it has the default prevented but it still reloads.

Answer (score 0):

I think (I'm not an expert with xhr) if you don't specify

```
window.location //or
window.redirect
```

Your browser "reload" the last URL you have. When you submit automatically, try to add a redirection to your desired link.

Comment: i don't wan't to redirect. the data is supposed  to be displayed since it`s a ajax request. but it reloads and does not let this happen